# its possible start a local selenium task, from a webserver?

Tags: python, selenium

I am thinking to develop some automatic task from selenium, today i doit from my local computer, with a local browser. Im looking to deploy this python app in a webserver, and I need to know if exist any way to start a local selenium browser from an app deployed on a webserver.

Comment: I was able to successfully host a pyppeteer-using server on heroku. Selenium would likely work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any cloud computing company (azure, google cloud, AWS - just to name a few). most of them offers free trials with balance that can be sufficient for a few months depending upon what resources you need.

once you have an account with one of this services you need to setup a virtual machine. I installed Ubuntu Linux and I used it with RDP to connect to a Desktop GUI interface. I installed the driver for the browser I wanted to use and just activated my script.

this took me around 2 hours to setup and it was my first time doing this ever.